# Standard practice for tracking a redirect page?

Tags: javascript

How can I add google analytics tracking code to a page that redirects.

For example say I have a vanity url www.simpleurl.com that is redirected to www.hardtorememberlongurlofdoom.com/folder/?q=qwerqwe

What would the best method be to track hits to the simpleurl.com. Currently Im using the redirect feature from my hosting company. What I think I should do is turn that off and create and index.html that runs the tracking JS and then redirects the page.

Does anyone know if there is a standard practice for this technique?

Comment: **Definitely** not JS; use a server-side language like PHP.

Comment: How would I get the Google Analytics JS to execute? Doesn't the PHP redirect before the JS loads?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you should track the visits with PHP, not JS.

Comment: Oh ok. I will do some research on that right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track it with JavaScript and not by using PHP on the simple domain (before the redirect) then you could set the script to track on the long domain and filter by referrer? You can get the referrer using `document.referrer`.

Another solution could be to set up Google Analytics to track by referrer on all visits and then you've got data to see how many goes through the (or maybe even several) simple domain(s) and how many goes straight to the long domain.

**EDIT:**
Actually you could just have the tracker on the long domain and all the data should be fine in Google Analytics: [Here](http://searchengineland.com/how-to-get-full-referral-content-urls-from-google-analytics-149549)
The only problem with this approach would be if you want information about the referrer from the simple domain.